# How to hide "Local Variables:" specification at the end of a file or how to prevent "M->" from get into that region

Tags: motion, file-local-variables

In emacs, file local variables are put at the end of the file. On appending text to a file, the user has to navigate to the exact line before the `Local Variables:` line - you can't not just `M->` and get there.

Appending text is more common than prepending, why not put the local variable specification on the front of the file?

If we can't change the behavior, how do I quickly get to that line? or perhaps how to just hide the file local variable part completely?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> why not put the local variable specification on the front of the file?

You *can* alternatively put file-local variables at the very top of the file.

See the Emacs manual, node [Specifying File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

As for this:

> how do I quickly get to that [`Local Variables:`] line?

`C-s Local V`

Comment: Suppose I want this to be file local     (setq org-odt-table-styles
          '("Academic" "Academic"
            ((use-first-row-styles . t)
             (use-last-row-styles . nil))))

Comment: I am not sure hot to set those multiple line variable correctly. It doesn't seem to fit the header line. By the way, use isearch to jump is definitely too cumbersome, since it's a quite common movement. A better method would be modifing M->.

Comment: So what prevents you from doing that? Write a function that goes to the local variables section (if there is one) or to the end of the buffer (if there isn't one) and rebind `M->` to that.

Comment: OP: Please don't change the question after there are answers. And please don't pose additional how-to questions in comments - post them as questions instead.